# Highcharts Solid Gauge Legend Symbol

Tags: highcharts

Is it possible to style the legend symbol for a solid gauge? I'm need the legend symbols to be colored squares but adding `squareSymbol: true` isn't working. Here's a fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/0krjsy5n/

```
legend: {
    squareSymbol: true
},

series: [{
    name: 'Speed',
    data: [80],
    showInLegend: true,
    dataLabels: {
        format: '<div style="text-align:center"><span style="font-size:25px;color:' +
            ((Highcharts.theme && Highcharts.theme.contrastTextColor) || 'black') + '">{y}</span><br/>' +
               '<span style="font-size:12px;color:silver">km/h</span></div>'
    },
    tooltip: {
        valueSuffix: ' km/h'
    }
}]
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The legend symbol is a representation of the series marker. You can manipulate the legend symbol by editing the series marker. For other charts this will alter the marker shown in the series, but in your case (for gauge) the marker is never shown in the actual graph.

For example, in your case ([JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/0krjsy5n/1/)):

```
series: [{
    marker: {
        symbol: 'square', // Make it a square
        fillColor: 'red', // With color red
    },
    lineWidth: 0 // With no line going through it
    // ...
}]
```

Comment: This is almost working for me. The only thing missing is that the square is not being colored. The only difference that I'm using the angular highcharts directive - highcharts-ng.